# Python Flask not working properly on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, flask, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run a flask app on my Windows 10 laptop through Bash on Ubunutu on Windows, but I am getting the following error:

None 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 126, in 
    app.run(debug=True) #Deubug is set to true
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 841, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 720, in run_simple
    s.bind((hostname, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied

I am not trying to run a restricted port. It should be on port 5000.
Here are the commands I ran:

- sudo apt-get install python-pip
- sudo pip install Flask
- sudo pip install flask-bootstrap
- sudo pip install bokeh
- python app.py

Whenever Flask was installed, I got back a warning:
The directory '/home/User/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/User/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Also, running sudo python app.py does not help either.

Any thoughts on what is happening?

Comment: you know it would help a lot if we had the code to see what you did....

Comment: never use sudo pip install, install every library in virtualenvironment